# How to use executable file within AWS lambda handler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I want to use executable file within AWS lambda handler function.
Here is my handler function where I want to use executable

```
func handler(){
    cmd := exec.Command("./balance", "GetBalance", id)
    cmd.Dir = "/Users/xxxx/go/src/getBalance"
    output, err := cmd.Output()
}
```

I want to use the output of the above command in this handler. Is it possible to use? If possible, do I need to zip both executables? Or is there any other way where I can use executable within the handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you will **not be able** to write to `/Users/xxxx/go/src/getBalance`. In lambda, you have access only to `/tmp`.

Also, if you bundle the `balance` file with your deployment package it will be stored in `/var/task` alongside your function code.

EDIT:

Based on the new comments, to complete solution also required removal of  `cmd.Dir` and recompilation of `balance` for linux.

Comment: So if I bundle `balance` with my deployment package, it will be stored in `/var/task`? So do i need to use `/var/task` instead of  `/Users/xxxx/go/src/getBalance` or do i need to do any modification to my `exec.Command`?

Comment: @Sharath It will be in `/var/task/`. I don't know if your current command is correct or not. I don't know what is `./balance`. It may require some dependencies to run not available in lambda. You have to just try and see how it goes. Only you know what `./balance` is, whether it requires any arguments, external libraries, files.

Comment: `./balance` requires two arguments. It will be like `./balance GetBalance 12345` where `12345` is `id` which is variable. It will give balance of `id`. It doesn't require any dependencies. I compiled it into linux environment. it is working fine with my other binary. But I don't know how to do with lambda. I will try using `/var/task`.

Comment: Thank you. I found out that I don't need to add any path if I bundle both the binaries together. I just use `exec.Command` without `cmd.Dir`. One more thing I was doing wrong before is that I didn't compile `balance` to linux environment. Now I compiled into linux and not using `cmd.Dir`. Now it is working.

Comment: @Sharath Thanks for letting me know. I can add the extra info to the answer :-)